# Facebook OAuthException code 1 when asking for location

Tags: facebook

my facebook chatbot is working perfectly, to the moment I ask the user for location like this:

```
    messageData = {
        recipient: {
            id: recipientId,
        },
        message: {
            text: messageText,
            quick_replies: els,
        },
    };
    callSendAPI(messageData);
```

then I get this as an error:

```
error: 
  { message: 'An unknown error has occurred.',
    type: 'OAuthException',
    code: 1,
    fbtrace_id: 'GqqNEKrrhDs' }
```

what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I should have been doing this:

```
    messageData = {
        recipient: {
            id: recipientId,
        },
        message: {
            text: messageText,
            quick_replies: [
                {
                    content_type: 'location',
                },
            ]
        },
    };
```

Comment: Notice the `[` `]` braces